# What is the difference between a PreBuildEvent, BeforeBuild target and BeforeCompile target in MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task, appharbor

I recently had to move some code from a [PreBuildEvent in Visual Studio into the BeforeBuild target to make it work on AppHarbor](http://blog.dantup.com/2011/05/setting-up-nuget-to-automatically-fetch-packages-when-deploying-to-appharbor-without-storing-binaries-in-source-control). While doing so, I also noticed a BeforeCompile target.

What is the difference between these three seemingly similar events: PreBuildEvent, BeforeBuild Target, BeforeCompileTarget?

What can/can't be done with each, and why would you pick one over another?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found in the `Microsoft.Common.targets` file which can be found (depending on wether you're using the 64-bit or 32-bit framework) at: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.target` for 64-bit and 
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets` for the 32-bit runtime. This file defines all the steps a build of your project undergoes. Quoting the source:

```
<!--
============================================================
                                    Build

The main build entry point.
============================================================
-->
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
        BeforeBuild;
        CoreBuild;
        AfterBuild
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The code is nice enough to explain the use of the `BeforeBuild` and `AfterBuild` target in the comments for both targets.

```
<!--
============================================================
                                    BeforeBuild

Redefine this target in your project in order to run tasks just before Build
============================================================
-->
<Target Name="BeforeBuild"/>

<!--
============================================================
                                    AfterBuild

Redefine this target in your project in order to run tasks just after Build
============================================================
-->
<Target Name="AfterBuild"/>
```

This is followed by the definition of the `CoreBuild` target:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CoreBuildDependsOn>
        BuildOnlySettings;
        PrepareForBuild;
        PreBuildEvent;
        ResolveReferences;
        PrepareResources;
        ResolveKeySource;
        Compile;
        UnmanagedUnregistration;
        GenerateSerializationAssemblies;
        CreateSatelliteAssemblies;
        GenerateManifests;
        GetTargetPath;
        PrepareForRun;
        UnmanagedRegistration;
        IncrementalClean;
        PostBuildEvent
    </CoreBuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So the `Build` target is just a wrapper around the `CoreBuild` target to enable you to perform custom steps just before or after the `CoreBuild` target. As can be seen above the `PreBuildEvent` and `PostBuildEvent` are listed as dependencies of the `CoreBuild` target. The dependencies of the `Compile` target are defined as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CompileDependsOn>
        ResolveReferences;
        ResolveKeySource;
        SetWin32ManifestProperties;
        _GenerateCompileInputs;
        BeforeCompile;
        _TimeStampBeforeCompile;
        CoreCompile;
        _TimeStampAfterCompile;
        AfterCompile
    </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Again `BeforeCompile` and `AfterCompile` are commented in the code:

```
<!--
============================================================
                                    BeforeCompile

Redefine this target in your project in order to run tasks just before Compile.
============================================================
-->
<Target Name="BeforeCompile"/>

<!--
============================================================
                                    AfterCompile

Redefine this target in your project in order to run tasks just after Compile.
============================================================
-->
<Target Name="AfterCompile"/>
```

Given this information I do not know why AppHarbor does not support `Pre-, PostBuildEvent` while the `Build` can be modified using `Before-, AfterBuild`.

Choosing which `Target` to override for which scenario depends on the moment during the build at which you wish to perform your given task. The targets do not have specific restrictions and/or benefits as to what they can accomplish. Apart from the fact that they can adapt `ItemGroup`'s or properties that were defined/filled by previous steps.

Using nuget to bring in packages is probably best performed before the build tries to resolve the projects dependencies. So `BeforeCompile` is not a good candidate for this kind of action.

I hope this sheds some light on the matter. Found another nice explanation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: To expand on this, msbuild reads the list of files involved in the compile process between BeforeBuild and BeforeCompile. If you use a task that emits a file you use as a build input, it needs to happen in BeforeBuild; if you do it in BeforeCompile, the file *will* be emitted, but then msbuild will complain that it can't find it.

Comment: Be sure to note, none of this applies to C++ project files (.vcxproj). It applies to C# projects only.

Comment: For ones who want to read more about targets. I paste this link here because I didn't find any useful **clean** target to interfere with : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019#default-build-targets